# Vectorize ifelse command in R

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

I have this example data

```
    library(quantmod)
    getSymbols("NOK",from="2013-01-01",to="2014-05-01",src="yahoo","getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
    data<-NOK
    w1<-1
    L_dO<-data[,1]
      L_dC<-data[,4]
      L_Profit_L_1<-((lag(L_dC,-1)-lag(L_dO,-1))/(lag(L_dO,-1)))*100
      L_Profit_L_2<-((lag(L_dC,-2)-lag(L_dO,-1))/(lag(L_dO,-1)))*100
      L_Profit_L_3<-((lag(L_dC,-3)-lag(L_dO,-1))/(lag(L_dO,-1)))*100
      L_Profit_L_4<-((lag(L_dC,-4)-lag(L_dO,-1))/(lag(L_dO,-1)))*100
      L_Profit_L_5<-((lag(L_dC,-5)-lag(L_dO,-1))/(lag(L_dO,-1)))*100
      L_Profit_L_all<-ifelse(L_Profit_L_1>w1,L_Profit_L_1,
                             ifelse(L_Profit_L_2>w1,L_Profit_L_2,
                                    ifelse(L_Profit_L_3>w1,L_Profit_L_3,
                                           ifelse(L_Profit_L_4>w1,L_Profit_L_4,
                                           ifelse(L_Profit_L_5>w1,L_Profit_L_5,L_Profit_L_5)))))
```

What am I interested in is `L_Profit_L_all`, but I see this is a bit strange and slow way to write it. I have tried to vectorize it like

```
L_Profit_L_all<-ifelse(c(L_Profit_L_1>w1,L_Profit_L_2>w1,L_Profit_L_3>w1,L_Profit_L_4>w1,L_Profit_L_5>w1),c(L_Profit_L_1,L_Profit_L_2,L_Profit_L_3,L_Profit_L_4,L_Profit_L_5),L_Profit_L_5)
```

But th result is not the same. I want it to work in right order, i.e. if the first if condition is TRUE, then return first else condition (and don't care about if another condition is TRUE which is able to do the first code)
Any straightforward how to achieve it? I have a huge dataset so every ms is good to save. Thanks

Comment: see the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902821/create-column-with-grouped-values-based-on-another-column-in-dplyr/27902924#27902924

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how you might approach the problem without any `ifelse`s. Assume you `cbind` all your L_Profit_L_X vectors together to get something similar to m in my example.

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(-5:5, 50, T), ncol = 5)
indx <- max.col(m > 1, ties.method = "first")
sapply(seq_along(indx), function(i) m[i, indx[i]])
#[1] 5 2 2 4 3 4 5 2 4 3
```

This is not fully vectorized since we're using `sapply` but I'm sure it will be a lot faster than the initial approach with 5 nested `ifelse`s.

#### Update

You can vectorize the code by replacing the `sapply` part above with:

```
m[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m)), indx)]
# [1] 5 2 2 4 3 4 5 2 4 3
```